# how to save camera pose in image exported from blender?

Tags: python, image-processing, blender

I have a script that renders and saves some images with Blender. Each of these images is taken from a different perspective.

Another script takes the images and does some image processing operations.
To do these operations, however, i need to recover the camera position and orientation.

Is there a way, when i save the rendered images, to "incorporate" in some way the position and orientation of the camera in the image, so that i can recover them when i load the images later? Or is it better just to save the sequence in another file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58916/script-for-save-camera-position-to-file